# Suricata / Filebeat / ELK - iptables tee - Create virtual hosts

Tags: iptables, elasticsearch, ids, filebeat, suricata

I have an IDS setup as follow:

### Hardware / interfaces

```
WAN <----(brwan)> ROUTER / AP <(br0)----> LAN
                                    \
                                     -----(eth1)> |
                                      \           | IDS device listening on eth1
                                       ---(eth0)> |
```

On the router, I use these iptables rules to tee the traffic to the IDS:

```
-A INPUT ! -s IDS_ETH1_IP/32 ! -i lo -j TEE --gateway IDS_ETH1_IP
-A FORWARD ! -s IDS_ETH1_IP/32 ! -d IDS_ETH1_IP/32 -j TEE --gateway IDS_ETH1_IP
-A OUTPUT ! -d IDS_ETH1_IP/32 ! -o lo -j TEE --gateway IDS_ETH1_IP
```

IDS_ETH1_IP is a fixed IP, outside of my LAN subnet.

Still on the router, the route to IDS_ETH1_IP is set:

```
~$ ip r s
(…)
IDS_ETH1_IP dev br0 scope link
```

On the IDS device, eth1 is setup this way:

```
~$ ip a s dev eth1
3: eth1: <BROADCAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether IDS_ETH1_MAC brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet IDS_ETH1_IP/32 scope global noprefixroute eth1
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

With the following commands to make sure it is only a listening device:

```
ip link set dev eth1 multicast off
ethtool -K eth1 gro off gso off lro off rx off rxvlan off sg off tso off tx off txvlan off
ethtool -G eth1 rx 4096

iptables -t raw -F PREROUTING
iptables -t raw -A PREROUTING -i eth1 -j DROP
```

Note: I need to leave ARP on on the interface, because if I enable NOARP, then the MAC is unknown by the various switches, and therefore the packets are teed to every device/interface on the LAN (except WiFi).

And sysctl settings (still on the IDS device):

```
net.ipv4.conf.eth1.accept_redirects = 0
net.ipv4.conf.eth1.accept_source_route = 0
net.ipv4.conf.eth1.forwarding = 0
net.ipv4.conf.eth1.promote_secondaries = 0
net.ipv4.conf.eth1.secure_redirects = 0
net.ipv4.conf.eth1.send_redirects = 0
net.ipv4.conf.eth1.shared_media = 0
net.ipv4.conf.eth1.rp_filter = 0
net.ipv4.conf.all.arp_ignore = 1
```

`all.arp_ignore` is essential to force the interfaces to only answer to their own arp queries.

### Software

On the IDS device, I have installed Suricata (listening to eth1 with AF_PACKETS) and Filebeat to ship the data to another device on my LAN that has an ELK docker stack (Elasticsearch, Kibana and Evebox).

It took me a little while to set all of that up and finally reach the setup described here, and it works quite well.

### The question

Now, the great thing about using iptables TEE rules on the router, is that I decide where to tap. I do after my firewall rules on the WAN side (no need to have alerts for already blocked packets), and it allows to know where the packets are going/coming from in the LAN with what is tapped on the FORWARD table. It also taps what is going in and out of the router itself (INPUT / OUTPUT).

What I would like to do, is find a way to separate on the log what is tapped on the LAN side from the WAN side. I could elaborate the iptables rules to separate `-i brwan`, `-o brwan` and `-i br0`, `-o br0` for example, this is easy enough, but how to distinguish these in the packets being teed? Marking packets does not go between devices.
Maybe on the IDS device creating sub-interfaces of eth1 with different IPs and MACs? and tee accordingly?
If I do that, how to create different *virtual* devices with filebeat so I can differentiate them in kibana?

Any idea on what I could do to reach that? And to improve my IDS system with what I have?

Thank you.